# Image in tbody overlaps thead on print

Tags: css, printing, html-table, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf from html.

In the html, there is a table with thead and tbody. I use Vue in order to generate the content:

```
<table class="data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="title" colspan="5">Control #@{{ index + 1 }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="number">#</th>
            <th>Tittel:</th>
            <th>Kommentar:</th>
            <th>Mangelpunkt<br> Registrert:</th>
            <th>Mangelpunkt<br> Utbedret:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-for="(checkpoint, cpIndex) in control.checkpoints">
        <tr>
            <td class="number">@{{ cpIndex + 1}}</td>
            <td>@{{ checkpoint.title }}</td>
            <td>@{{ checkpoint.comment }}</td>
            <td class="danger center">@{{ checkpoint.rejectedDate }}</td>
            <td class="success center">@{{ checkpoint.approvedDate }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="checkpoint.images.length > 0">
            <td class="number">@{{ cpIndex + 1 }}</td>
            <td class="images" colspan="4">
                <img v-for="(image, imgIndex) in checkpoint.images" :key="imgIndex" :src="base64Images[image]" alt="print image">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine in the browser, but if one image is tall enough to not fit on the same page as the other images, it breaks to the next page (as wanted). **However**, the image is overlapping the thead..

[image]

I've tried to apply all sorts of hacks to this the last hours but I simply cannot get the image to respect the thead on the next print page..

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?